# How to retain text which is present inside a tag after using beautifulsoup package in python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a html tag which is as follows

```html
<a href="http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/134.html">CWE-134</a>
```

I want to retain the href part inside

Please suggest any steps for doing so

Comment: retain? extract href or save it to file?

Answer (score 0):

Extract:

```
a_tag['href']
```

Save to file:

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(a_tag['href'])
```

Write it to a file, like TXT or CSV. Or store it to the database.

Answer (score 0):

```
for _ in soup.find_all('a'):
    print _
    text = re.split(r'">',re.split(r'="', str(_))[-1])[0]
    print text
```